# How to pass multiple values to web service in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, web-services, arguments, parameter-passing

I have created a form in VB.net, where on-click of a button multiple variables are passed to a web service. My code is as below :

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports OutlookAddIn2.mantistest
Dim QService As New MantisConnectPortTypeClient

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim value1 As String
        Dim value2 As String
        Dim value3 As String
        Dim value4 As String
        Dim viewstate As String


        value1 = Project_Name.SelectedItem.ToString()
        value2 = ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
        value3 = ComboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString()
        value4 = TextBox4.Text
        Dim s As String = String.Format("Value 1: {0}  value2 : {1} value3: {2} value4: {3}", value1, value2, value3, value4)
        Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(s)

        TextBox1.Text = QService.mc_issue_add(username:="**", password:="**", issue:="view_state:{0} project{1}")

    End Sub
```

The input parameters of my web service are :

1. Project
2. Category
3. Priority
4. Status

When I try to put them in following ways I get the following errors :

1. **Code :** `issue:=("Category:{0} project{1}",value1, value2)`
   **Error :**  `value1` saying that a named argument is expected.
2. **Code :** `TextBox1.Text = QService.mc_issue_add(username:="**", password:="**", view_state:=value1, Project:=value2)`
   *Error :* Argument not specified for parameter `issue` of public function `QService.mc_issue_add(Username as String, Password as String, issue as mantistest.Issuedata)As string`

Where have I gone wrong? I have tried using other arguments with single input values and it works fine. Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: You are inputting 'issue:="view_state:{0} project{1}"'inside call of method, so you are passing an unformatted string as argument! You have to format string before passing it in the methood.

Dim issueVar=String.Format("view_state:{0} project{1}",project,category)

Comment: yet gives the same error, `Value of type string cannot be converted to OutlookAddin2.matistest.Issuedata`

Comment: I think this is different error form error you wrote above. From your last error it seems that 'Issue' argument is of different type than string. If 'Issue' argument is object than you have to find from web service documentation how to build this argument.

Comment: `Function mc_issue_add(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal issue As mantistest.IssueData) As <System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name:="return"), System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(DataType:="integer")> String` This is the function for that particular module in the webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to describe the fields separately like this

```
    Dim mantNote As IssueData
    mantNote = New IssueData

    Dim idField As String
    idField = " "

    Dim view_stateField As ObjectRef
    view_stateField = New ObjectRef
    view_stateField.id = 10
    view_stateField.name = " "

    Dim last_updatedField As Date
    last_updatedField = Date.FromOADate(6 / 6 / 2016)

    Dim projectField As ObjectRef
    projectField = New ObjectRef
    projectField.id = 1
    projectField.name = "test"

    Dim categoryField As String
    categoryField = "test"
```

and add them under 1 description

```
    mantNote.id = idField
    mantNote.view_state = view_stateField
    mantNote.last_updated = last_updatedField
    mantNote.project = projectField
    mantNote.category = categoryField
    TextBox1.Text = QService.mc_issue_add(username:=" ", password:=" ", issue:=mantNote)
```